# Ambiguity in method invocation, with arguments type of Character and float

Tags: java, char, character

```
public class Main {  
    static void over_Var(float a, Character... ab) {
        System.out.println("Method1");
    }
    static void over_Var(Character... ab) {
        System.out.println("Method2");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        over_Var(1, 'm');
        over_Var('k', 'm');
    }
}
```

I'm getting error as this:

```
Main.java:19: error: reference to over_Var is ambiguous
    over_Var('k', 'm');
    ^
 both method over_Var(float, Character...) in Main and method over_Var(Character...) in Main 
 match 1 error
```

The code works fine if I use `char` instead of `Character`, or remove the line `over_Var('k', 'm');`

Why am I getting error like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why `over_Var(1, 'm');` is not ambiguous

`1` is an integer. It can't be passed to a parameter of type `Character` or `char` directly (without casts), so the only option is the `(float, Character...)` overload. There *does* exist an `int` to `float` widening primitive conversion, which is permitted in an [invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3).

You might have *thought* that `1` could be converted to a `Character` because you can do that in [assignment contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

```
Character a = 1;
```

However, this is purely because in the "Assignment Contexts" section of the JLS (see above link), there is this part that begins:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> [...]

The section for invocation contexts does not have this paragraph. So in reality, assignment contexts give constant expressions (like `1`) special treatment, allowing them to be converted to smaller types than they actually are. Invocation contexts do not do this.

#### Why `over_Var('k', 'm');` is ambiguous

In this case, both overloads are applicable. `'k'` is a `char`, and the conversion from `char` to `float` (widening primitive conversion again) is allowed in an invocation context. The conversion from `char` to `Character` is also allowed in a loose invocation context.

If there are multiple applicable methods, the compiler chooses the most specific one. Which is more specific? Well, the second parameter of both calls would be `Character`, so we just need to consider the first parameter's type. One's `float` and the other's `Character`. Which one of these is more specific depends on their subtyping relationship. According to the [subtyping rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), they are unrelated, so neither is more specific, and so you get a compiler error.

This is a simplification of the entire section of [15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) of the spec, which I strongly encourage you to explore yourself :)

#### Why changing to `char` works

Unlike `float` and `Character`, `float` and `char` actually are related! Specifically:

> - `double` is a super type of `float`
> - `float` is a super type of `long`
> - `long` is a super type of `int`
> - `int` is a super type of `char`
> - `int` is a super type of `short`
> - `short` is a super type of `byte`

So `char` is a subtype of `float`, so `over_Var(char...)` is more specific than `over_Var(float, char...)`, and hence will be preferred.

#### Some ways to resolve the ambiguity

To call `(float, Character...)`, you can just cast:

```
over_Var((float) 'k', 'm');
```

To call `(Character...)`, you can pass in a `Character[]`.

```
over_Var(new Character[] {'k', 'm'});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is *not* that you have variable length arguments. This is a `The method X is ambiguous for the type Y` [error](https://www.journaldev.com/9107/the-method-is-ambiguous-for-the-type-java-ambiguous-method-call-null-error), explained in the link:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation … The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

> java compiler doesn’t consider any of them to be more specific, hence the method ambiguous call error

**First of all... why the connection between chars and floats?**

That has to do with how chars work under the hood in Java.

Example:

```
System.out.println(200 - 'a'); // subtracting a char from 200
System.out.println(0 - 'a'); // subtracting a char from 0
```

Should Return:

```
103
-97
```

So what's the solution? You indicated one: change `Character` to `char`. But why does that work? You have stumbled upon **very interesting Java behavior**. Take this code for example:

```
public class Main {  
    static void over_Var(float a, Character b)   {
        System.out.println("Method1");
    }
    static void over_Var(char a, Character b) {
        System.out.println("Method2");
    }
    static void over_Var(Character a, Character b) {
        System.out.println("Method3");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        over_Var('k','m');
    }
}
```

- This *will have an error* due to ambiguity between the `char` and `Character`.
- Comment out the first function. It will still *have the error* due to ambiguity between `char` and `Character`
- Comment out the second function. *It will fail* due to ambiguity between `float` casted as `Character`, and `Character`
- Comment out the third function. It will print `Method2`. It knows to prioritize `char` over `float`!

This appears... to violate transitivity. char + Character = ambiguity. Character + float = ambiguity. But char + float = non-ambiguous? <s>I will leave you with the word "strange"</s>.

Edit: the reason for this (see Sweeper's better answer), is that it knows to prioritize `char` over `float` because they are *related types*; char is a subtype of float. On the other hand, Character is not related. (In other words, the reason for the apparent lack of "transitivity" is that specificity can only be assessed in the context of the types being compared.)